# Where to put libraries in a Netbeans Java EE web project? /lib or /web/WEB-INF/lib?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, libraries

I have a Spring-Hibernate-Jsf project. I want to ask what is the difference between WEB-INF/lib and /lib? Which is the best to put my jar packages?

I am using Netbeans IDE. Under my main directory which is WebApp, there are "build","dist","etc","lib"..."web" named folders. At first I put all my libraries to /lib but Spring-Security doesn't worked under this folder and After a little search I have found that It must be under WEB-INF/lib folder.

Now the project seems a little disorganized.

Comment: This is an IDE-specific question. What IDE are you talking about? Eclipse? Are you implying that you're able to put JARs directly in the "Web App Libraries" folder of a "Dynamic Web Project" type project? That shouldn't be.

Comment: @BalusC There are 2 folders which are WebApp->lib(Libraries) and WebApp->web->WEB-INF->lib.

Comment: Do you have a WAR or EAR project? It sounds like an EAR project where the `/web` folder represents the WAR part of the EAR. Again, telling about the IDE used and the project type would be helpful. You seem to be thinking that this is specific to Spring/Hibernate/JSF, but this isn't true. It's specific to Java EE spec and the IDE/tooling used.

Comment: @BalusC I added more information about problem.

Comment: Okay. I fixed bad title and tags. Hopefully you will now get the attention from the right people.